# Does limit exist?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $\mu$ is a positive, finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and we have that for $a$ $\neq$ $0$ we have that $\mu (\mathbb{R})<\infty$

$f(a)= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}d\mu (x)$

Does $\lim_{a\rightarrow0 } af(a)$ exist?

I think this might be pretty simple, but I'm not entirely sure. I tried constructing a sequence of functions and used dominating convergence theorem to show that the limit is 0. Is that possible, or am I missing something?

Comment: What if $\mu = \delta_0$?

Comment: You need to know the behavior of $\frac{d\mu (x)}{dx}$ as $x\to 0$